How is the continuous order and market book merged together at market close?
This question is specifically about how NASDAQ merges the two order books at market close in order to match orders, but I am guessing the same concepts apply to other on close/opening auction markets.
A explanation and a simple example is found in the following faq: https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/productsservices/Trading/ClosingCrossfaq.pdf
Most of this example is also posted at: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/optiver-trading-at-the-close/discussion/442669 which I replicate here
    3:50 p.m.:
    Paired Shares: 4,000
    Imbalance side: B
    Imbalance shares: 500
    Current ref px: $10.00
    Near: $0
    Far: $0

    3:55 p.m.:
    Buy 500 shares MOC received
    Paired Shares: 4,000
    Imbalance side: B
    Imbalance shares: 1,000
    Current ref px: $10.15
    Near: $10.25
    Far: $10.50

    3:56 p.m.-3:59 p.m.:
    Sell 1,000 shares IO received at $9.95
    Sell 1,000 shares LOC received at $10.10
    Sell 1,000 shares LOC received at $10.00
    Paired Shares: 5,000
    Imbalance shares: 0
    Imbalance side: N
    Near: $10.00
    Far: $10.00

    4:00 p.m.:
    Paired Shares: 5,000
    Imbalance shares: 0
    Imbalance side: N
    Auction Trades at $10.00

Another two simple examples to illustrate the cross price for matches at close are provided at: https://www.kaggle.com/code/tomforbes/optiver-trading-at-the-close-introduction
These are illustrated by the two following diagrams

and

where the crossing price (assuming market closes at this state) are \$9 and \$8 respectively, since in the first case the maximum number of matches is 5 units to be sold (with 1 unit left unsold) and the second case the maximum number of matches is 4 units to be bought (3 units not bought).
None of these examples clearly cover cases where Imbalance Only (IO) orders or Market on Close (MOC) orders get matched, nor in fact is it clear to me how Limit on Close orders are matched.
Some of my questions are:

Suppose in the example from the first diagram, all ask prices were limit at close orders. Then, which are the 5 units of the requested 6 sell units that get matched? Do orders get matched by price priority, or in order of when they were placed?
If orders are always matched in the order of when they were placed do we just pretend that there were 6 units for sale at \$9 instead of 4 units at \$9 and 4 units at \$8.

With what priority do IO and MOC orders, and orders from the continuous book get matched? E.g., continuing with the example from the first diagram, suppose that there was a IO buy order for 1 unit, and MOC buy order for 1 unit, and suppose that the Nasdaq BBO is \$9.25 x \$9.50. Then the IO buy order is priced at \$9.25 and presumably can be matched against the remaining 1 unit to be sold at \$9. Which of the IO and MOC orders gets matched?



This may be helpful, however I didn't manage to understand any more useful information from this reference. Let me know if you get anything from it.
https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/productsservices/trading/crosses/fact_sheet.pdf

Ok so I may be wrong but my instinct on how this works would be something like this. By "bring the book together", I believe this means that all orders from the continuously trading book (the normal limit order book) and the closing (or opening) cross book are combined. Meaning all orders which are unmatched in the normal book are dumped into the close crossing book at the end of trading.

Then I think what happens is this: Now that all orders are in the same book structure, we need a way to find an "auction price" for them. I think NASDAQ does something like optimize a price level such that the volume of traded orders is maximized. I recall reading something about this type of auction book in Bouchards book. The key here is that the auction book is sealed. Market participants cannot see the orders (best bid and best offer with volume) while trading is ongoing.

A bit more information on the auction book process: Market participants can enter orders into the auction book. The maintainer of the book will continuously optimize a price level to maximize the number of matched orders, and this price level is continuously published and made public information. But participants do not know how much of their orders are matched until the auction ends, at which point all information is released and orders are matched. Before the auction ends, participants can infer some information about what the market is doing from the published price value.

It's quite possible some of the information I have posted here is not quite right. Please do correct me if I haven't been fully accurate.
